# python bokeh not including Span in axes limits

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I'm plotting some data with bokeh's `Span`. I'm doing almost exactly the same as shown in the [documentation example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#spans), with the difference that my spans are outside the range of the data I'm plotting.

The problem is that the auto-calculated axis limits don't include where the spans are plotted, so the initial view of my graph doesn't include the spans.

I could manually calculate the axes limits from the span positions and declare the limits, but then I'll have to decide on a buffer to use which isn't particularly elegant if my dataset range varies from graph-to-graph. (And there's the possibility that sometimes the data *will* fall outside the range of the spans, so hardsetting limits based on the spans is not a good solution.)

So is there a way to get the Spans included in the calculation done behind the scenes for the axis limits?

Answer (score 1):

As of Bokeh 0.13, annotation (such as `Span`) do not participate in auto-ranging. Your options are:

- set the range manually, as you have said
- as a workaround, add an invisible glyph (e.g. a circle with zero alpha) at the same location as the span, to goose the `DataRange` to include it

Comment: I decided on adding checks whether the data range falls outside the Span or not, and adjusting the limits accordingly, but I think your second suggestion is better than that. I don't like having to manually set the buffer in my method, which doesn't scale well for difference data ranges.